# Converting LINQ to loops in C# using resharper

Tags: c#, .net, linq, resharper, resharper-6.0

I am using Resharper 6.1 and I am pretty sure there is a way to convert LINQ into the loops. They have listed that functionality as one of their version 6 features here.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/whatsnew_60.html#LINQtoLoops

it also "sometimes" allows me to do it by showing a little pop-up besides my code asking me if I want to convert the LINQ expression into a loop. But I am not sure under which condition does it show that little pop-up.

Any ideas?

Comment: @I4V If Stackoverflow does not allow anyone to post resharper questions then the tag "Reshareper" would not have almost 2000 questions on it.

Comment: @I4V, "look at the line 143 in your code..."?  Are you just trolling now?

Comment: Maybe you could supply examples of the code you're talking about? Because otherwise, I can't see what you're talking about.

Comment: @I4V ReSharper/Visual Studio/NUnit-related questions are also programming questions. But this particular question lacks a code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper is smart. But not smart enough to understand every linq query.

If it's simple enough to convert then reshaper will understand it's possible and will show you the hint (which you can control under Resharper -> Options -> Inspection Severity).

When the linq expression is not simple enough for resharper to understand it can't know how to convert it..